# Measure of how much a homeomorphism distorts a shape.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, soft-question, euclidean-geometry

Is there a measure of how much a homeomorphism distorts a shape?

In particular, consider the set of orientation preserving homeomorphisms between compact subsets of the euclidean plane. I am looking for a function $d$ from this set to $\mathbb R$ measuring how much $d$ distorts its domain. It should at least satisfy:

- Some consistency properties:

  - $d(id) = 0$
  - $d(f^{-1}) = d(f)$
  - $d(f \circ g) \le d(f) + d(g)$
- $d(f) = 0 \iff f \text { is a similarity}$

Are there any functions like this?

Comment: No.  What is d when the continuous image of a disconnected space is connected?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Whoops, meant homeomorphisms, not bijections. Fixed.

Comment: Then edit your question and title so it is correct but do not expect any homeomorphism that aren't bijections.  The non-sentence "Fixed." is meaningless.

Comment: Something involving the log of the max of the Lipschitz constants of $f$ and $f^{-1}$?

Comment: See also the distortion metric of [Schreiner et al. (2004) Sec. 5.2](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~jmschrei/ism.html), termed the "symmetric Dirichlet energy" by [Rabinovich et al. (2017)](https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/slim/).

Comment: @Rahul It does not seem like the lipschitz constant can distinguish between a similarity and other transformations. I am reading the paper in your second comment now.

Comment: @Rahul it seems the idea of computing how "non-similar" the jacobian matrix for a random point is a fruitful direction (as was suggested in the paper).

Comment: @Rahul Ah, I think I got it. Just compare the singular values of the jacobeans. If they are the same, no distortion has occurred. Otherwise, some has. If there are only one or zero, the map is not actually a homeomorphism.

Comment: You'll need to get $\log$ involved somewhere to satisfy $d(f\circ g)\le d(f)+d(g)$ instead of $d(f)d(g)$. Also you didn't say the homeomorphisms were diffeomorphisms.

Comment: @Rahul oh, that's true.